# REST API pagination with OGR

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr, arcgis-rest-api

I am using OGR to ETL data from an ArcGIS Map Service into PostGIS. When I run `ogrinfo` on the service, I see ~47000 records:

```
ogrinfo -so -al "https://maps.bouldercolorado.gov/arcgis/rest/services/general/BuildingFootprints/MapServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&returnGeometry=true&outFields=*&f=json"
...
Layer name: ESRIJSON
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 46629
Extent: (-105.634173, 39.918929) - (-105.128672, 40.177275)
...
```

I would like to extract all 47,000 records, and I've tried doing this by leveraging the open option for the ESRIJSON driver called `FEATURE_SERVER_PAGING` to no avail:

```
ogr2ogr \
-f PostgreSQL \
Pg:"dbname=mydb" \
ESRIJSON:"https://maps.bouldercolorado.gov/arcgis/rest/services/general/BuildingFootprints/MapServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&returnGeometry=true&outFields=*&orderByFields=OBJECTID+ASC&f=json" \
-nln "sandbox.buildings" \
-oo "FEATURE_SERVER_PAGING=YES" \
-t_srs "EPSG:2876" \
-overwrite
```

The [documentation](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/esrijson.html#vector-esrijson) for this driver seems to suggest that pagination will happen automatically even without the feature server paging parameter set, but I only ever get 2000 results when I query the new table in PostgreSQL.

How do I extract all 47000 records with OGR using the command line interface?

The ArcGIS Server is 10.8, GDAL/OGR is 3.3.1, PostgreSQL is 13.3, PostGIS is 3.1.3

Comment: this tool https://github.com/openaddresses/pyesridump